# Explanation about the volatile keyword in C

Tags: c, volatile

Can someone give me an explanation about the use of the second volatile keyword in this line

```
volatile unsigned int * volatile buffer;
```

I know that the volatile keyword is usually used to indicate to the compiler that a variable's value may change at any time without any action being taken by the code the compiler finds nearby. This prevents the compiler from optimizing or caching the variable excessively, ensuring that the variable is always accessed from memory rather than from cached values. But what about the second one.

thank you all for your help

Comment: [C Gibberish](https://cdecl.org) says *"declare buffer as volatile pointer to volatile unsigned int"*

Comment: `volatile unsigned int` can also be written `unsigned int volatile`, which means that `volatile unsigned int * volatile` can also be written `unsigned int volatile * volatile`. It possibly requires fewer mental gymnastics when written that way because it makes the `volatile` qualifier consistently refer to the thing to its left.

Comment: Read declaration from right to left: `buffer` is a `volatile *` to `integer` which is `unsigned` and `volatile`. This might help: https://medium.com/@bartobri/untangling-complex-c-declarations-9b6a0cf88c96

Answer (score 4):

`volatile unsigned int * volatile buffer;`

It means: "*volatile pointer to volatile unsigned int*"

Both pointer and referenced object are `volatile`

```
volatile unsigned int * volatile buffer;
 ^^^                      ^^^
 ^^^                      ^^^-volatile pointer
 ^^^
 ^^^-volatile unsigned int
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is mandatory to use the second volatile keyword? Can you give me example where it can be useful to declare the pointer in itself volatile?

Comment: @Jee: If the location of the buffer is going to change while the software is running, you need `buffer` to be volatile, so that the compiler will ensure the program sees the change. But, from your other comment, it sounds like the buffer location is set once at the beginning. For that, you need to get it once, possibly from some volatile location, after which you can keep your own copy in a non-volatile variable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, If I understand correctly, I need to declare this buffer volatile because the address is sent during run time. It might also change depending on the reset. For example if core1 reset and not core 2, for some reason, the address of this buffer is send back to core2.

Comment: @Jee no - if the address is changed by something not in the normal program execution. Side effect prone.

Answer (score 3):

```
volatile int * x;
```

The pointer points to some integer that can change at any time, can be read at any time and so on.

However, the pointer itself (this means: the variable `x`) only changes if the program assigns a value (it is not `volatile`).

```
int * volatile y;
```

The variable `y` (this means: the pointer itself) may change at any time.

However, it points to an integer value that only changes if the program assigns a value.

```
volatile int * volatile z;
```

The variable `z` may change at any time. And the integer it points to may also change at any time.

With more levels of indirection, more combinations are possible:

```
int * * volatile w1;
volatile int * * w2;
volatile int * * volatile w3;
volatile int * volatile * w4;
...
```

The same principly applies to `const`, too:

```
const int * a;
int * const b;
const int * const c;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `... *volatile` means that the pointer variable itself is volatile. Which is not something you would normally need to use, since a compiler already ought to disable optimizations on that pointer variable given that it points at `volatile` data.

In theory, if the pointer is a hardware address register, it might perhaps make sense to make the pointer itself `volatile`. I can't recall that I have ever seen it used even in low-level embedded systems code though.

Code with excessive qualifier spam like `void func (volatile const int* n volatile const)` is most often just an indicator that the programmer does not quite know what they are doing, or that they like to "pose" knowledge of mostly useless language features. There *are* uses of `...* const` but that's another story.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This buffer is used to share data, in ram, between two core of my mcu. The address of this buffer is shared between the core during initialization and used to share data afterward. I was wondering if the second volatile was mandatory or not, since as you already pointed, the data in itself is declare volatile.

Comment: “a compiler already ought to disable optimizations on that pointer variable given that it points at `volatile` data” is false. Given `volatile unsigned int *buffer;`, the compiler has no reason to expect the value of `buffer` to be changed by any external means and should presume it remains unchanged. Fetching it from memory every time it is used would make no more sense than recalculating the address of a `buffer` defined `volatile unsigned int buffer[128];` every time `buffer` is used. It has a fixed address and does not move, and the `buffer` pointer has a stored value and does not change.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Optimizing is not just about not re-reading the variable from memory. In hardware-related programming you could have an ISR hardware callback which shares this variable at file scope. If the ISR does change the variable and the background program believes the ISR is never called, then that would mean that strange and potentially incorrect optimizations may get carried out. ->

Comment: My observation is that compilers tend to _not_ do such strange optimizations if the pointer points at volatile-qualified data. It is a quality of implementation not to break even though the pointer was not declared as `volatile int* volatile` etc.